# Is there a way to temporarily disable existing alert emails from executing?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, alert

I have a powershell script the runs automatically once a week to move old list items to an archive list. On the current list my end users are receiving alerts when the item is moved (create/deleted) from the list.

I found a code sample for powershell that is suppose to stop the alert emails, but all it seems to do is just remove the ability to create new alerts by disabling the button.

```
## To enable alerts for Web application

$SPwebapp=Get-SPWebApplication "http://SharePointSite.com"

# To Disable alerts for a Web application
$SPwebapp.AlertsEnabled = $false
$SPwebapp.Update()
```

Does anyone know of a way to temporarily disable existing email alerts so I can run my script without users getting alert emails for sharepoint 2013? If possible in powershell.

Answer (score 4):

If you have developer knowledge, you can interrupt the email alerts, according to :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx. We have used it to modify the email alert.

The other solution is to filter them in exchange, but the exchange guy won't be very happy